# What is the best practice working with OAuth, express and React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, oauth-2.0

I don't quite understand the workflow of Third-Party Authentication.
I am trying to create an SPA application with back-end on express and front-end on React.
The application should handle webhooks from GitHub API.

I've managed to authenticate the user on my back-end but how do i send the access_token to the front end? (So i can do ajax on front-end).
GitHub allows to send ajax requests with token bearer.
Example:
`curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com/user`

Do i send the JWT token instead to the front-end via query string? But then what do i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an endpoint to your web back end such as GET /token. However, this would need to be protected via an authentication cookie that your web back end issues.

If you are building an SPA then an alternative option (which I prefer) is to be entirely cookieless. This is done via the following steps:

- Implement authentication via the [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) library
- After login the browser will receive an access token and can send it to GitHub
- Use Express only to serve web static content

If interested in this approach, have a look at these resources of mine:

- [SPA and API Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)
- [React SPA Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final)